# How to run multiple environment in once

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I got two configuration file for different environments which share the same source file `source.py`, the source code is about seven hundred lines long. I used to run them separately, I mean `python source.py` to apply `config_1.ini` and `python source.py` to apply `config_2.ini`.

Now I want to run them in one process, I would like to apply multiprocessing in this case as these two environments are isolated. but I don't know how to implement. any suggestion would be appreciated.

`config_1.ini`

```
[Log]
Name = xxx_xxx_xxx
Path = /usr/local/xx/logs/
Level = INFO
When = midnight
Interval = 1
Max Counter = 0
Format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s'
[Concurrency]
Max Workers = 16
Consume Number = 1
[Message Queue]
Host = xx.xxx.xxx.xx
Port = 2242
Virtual Host = /
Username = Osk
Password = 112342
Durable = True
Delivery Mode = 2
Paper Request Queue = xxRequest
Paper Response Queue = xxResponse
Info Request Queue = YYRequest
Info Response Queue = YYResponse
[Download]
Path = /usr/local/xx/images/
Retry Times = 3
Timeout = 5
[Upload]
Token URL = http://abcs.com/upload/token/
[Redis]
Host = xx.xxx.xxx.xx
Port = 6232
Password = 123456
Database = 4
Timeout = 172800
```

I thought about reading the 2 configuration file in a loop, but I guess the one will affect another since the existence of MessageQueue.

Or is there other ways beside of multiprocessing to implement this?

Comment: What are the differences between your environments? How does your script know which .ini to use?

Comment: @IcedLance there is this `config_path` in my `source.py`.

Comment: @IcedLance The difference is the different configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the script take the name of the ini-file to use from `sys.argv[1]`.

Then on the command-line you can simply do:

```
python source.py config_1.ini &
python source.py config_2.ini &
```

(The `&` is how to detach the process from the terminal in a UNIX shell. With ms-windows `cmd.exe` you have to use `start python source.py config_1.ini`, et cetera)

Comment: Thank you very much, but this means I still have to run `python source.py` for 2 times. I want to run  `python source.py` only for one time.

Comment: Now matter how you do it, if you want to run it with two configurations, you are *effectively* running it twice... Just put the two python invocations in a shell script or batch file.

Comment: That's right, my idea didn't reduce any space usage or time usage.  So multi-processing is not fit for my case, right?

Comment: And your method helps me avoid one command `python source.py` to initiate two environments.

Comment: will it work like `python source.py config_1.ini & ;python source.py config_2.ini &`? I am worried that the second method won't be executed because the first one is never finished.

Comment: `python source.py config_1.ini` keeps listening to the message queue and processing, and do that over and over again. won't that stop the second from executing if execute them in the same shell.

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon Regarding both your last comments. If you detach the script from the terminal using `&`, the terminal is free to execute other commands. I don't see how a message queue would have anything to do with that.

Comment: Thank for replying, It makes sense when running my script in backgrounds, no output in the current terminal, yet when I test with a dead loop. `test.py`, the content is `while True: print(0)`, then I run `python test.py &`, what I expected is there is no output, and I can continue running the same command `python test.py &`, but the result the first command keeps printing in current window, I have no way to run another one behind it.

Comment: Then you have to redirect the output of both commands to different files.